# Number of blocks in a Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I know the number of blocks or subsystems of the same kind, in a Simulink model, from Matlab (.m file)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried find_system? You can search by BlockType.

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works to count the terminators, for exemple, but it doesn't work with my subsystems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

```
>> doc sldiagnostics
```

and in particular

```
>> nBlocks = sldiagnostics('modelname','CountBlocks');
```

Note that sldiagnostics tells you how many of each type of block, so you'll need to parse it out, and do some math, to get the total block count.

There is a discussion of doing something similar [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2009/08/11/how-many-blocks-are-in-that-model/)

Comment: Thank you. Here is what I did:


    `[txtRpt, sRpt] = sldiagnostics('modelName', 'CountBlocks');  
    Index = 1;  
    while (~strcmp(sRpt(Index).type, 'TypeOfBlock'))  
        Index = Index + 1 ;  
    end  
    NbBlocks = sRpt(Index).count;`